# How to override a parent event listener when a child element is clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding

How do I override `aFunction` inside of  `child.js`?

I want the child event listener to trigger without `aFunction` triggering, and I can't modify `parent.js`.

Is this even possible?

### index.html:

```
       <th class="foo">foo &nbsp;&nbsp;

            <span class="bar" data-feather="arrow-down"></span>

        </th>
```

### parent.js:

```
       parent = {
            init: function() {
                parent.aFunction($('.foo'));
            },
            aFunction: function(element) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                    alert('foo');
                });
            }, ...

         window.onload = parent.init;
```

child.js:

```
    $('.bar').on('click', function() {
      alert('bar');
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First its `.bar` cause no html tags called `bar`
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) *Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*

**Example**

```js
$('.foo').on('click', function() {
  alert('foo');
});
$('.bar').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('bar');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">foo &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="bar" data-feather="arrow-down">Bar</span>
</div>
```